# Get tweets from a keyword without any api as there is a restiction of 450

Tags: twitter, tweets

Using the url I am getting the tweets for the keywords I want a search in the tweeter

```
https://twitter.com/search-home
```

Now is there any url which I can call which will return me the json so that I can parse it and display the tweets to the user in his mobile?

Like this url

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=50&q=abelvros
```

but it gives me an error.

Comment: Did you even read the error msg? It answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API has certain restrictions regarding the time and amount of data.

Take a look:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

There's absolutely nothing you can legally do to get around it.